# Is there a way to make this shorter with an Or operator?

Tags: javascript

I would like to do this shorter?

```
function getRedditImg (img) {
  if (img === 'default') {
    return 'https://i.imgur.com/pMkc6Lo.png'
  } else if (img === 'self') {
    return 'https://i.imgur.com/pMkc6Lo.png'
  }
  return img
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
post.thumbnail === ( 'default' || 'self') ? 'https://i.imgur.com/pMkc6Lo.png' : post.thumbnail
```

But, it short circuits of default its true...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `return img === 'default' || img === 'self' ? 'https://i.imgur.com/pMkc6Lo.png' : img`? Your `( 'default' || 'self')` evaluates to `'default` because it's truthy

Comment: `return ['default', 'self'].includes(img) ? 'https://i.imgur.com/pMkc6Lo.png' : img;`

Comment: thanks @connexo, if you add it as answer ill accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it witch the switch case syntax

```
  switch(expression) {
     case x:
        // code block
        break;
      case y:
        // code block
         break;
     default:
        // code block
   }
```